# RavenDB : When should prefer Delta documents

Tags: c#, ravendb

*PS: Delta documents just similar to cache docs.
Could anyone help me in understanding when should I go with the delta documents, while using Raven DB?*

I will rephrase my scenario initially I had `Product` document, as name explicitly says its only product name, description etc.

Now, I need product user reviews. Should I go with saving the same product document or should go with `ProductReview` document.

Here, product review document is a delta for me.

Comment: Your question makes almost no sense. What are delta documents in the context of RavenDB? What are cache documents? Are these the same thing as *cached* documents? If so then Raven automatically caches all read operations. What are you asking here?

Comment: @tomredfern Thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: Will you ever need to display the review documents by themselves without the product?

Comment: Yes. As of now the review are in Disqus,But i am now moving into our system.

Comment: Then you should probably store them separately.

Comment: Then again, it depends how you have structured your domain. Have you heard the term *aggregate* in the context of domain modelling?

Comment: Yes. I have heard about it. But never had a look on it. But here once again does Domain Modelling comes in NoSql DB ?

Comment: No but you should be able to use your domain model to make these kinds of decisions around what things belong with what other things in nosql